# An exercise about splitting fields and extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory

Let $F$ $\subseteq$$E$$\subseteq$$K$ consecutive field extensions and $f$$\in$$F[X]$ a nonconstant polynomial.Prove that if $K$ is a splitting field of $f$ over $F$ ,then $K$ is a splitting field of $f$ over $E$.

What i did is: By the definition of splitting field $\exists$ $a_1,a_2,,,,a_m$ $\in$ $K$,$m=deg(f)$ such that $f(ai)=0$ $\forall$ $i=1,2,,,m$ and $K=F[a_1,,,a_m]$.

But $K=F[a_1,,,a_m]$  $\subseteq$ $E[a_1,,,,a_m]$ thus $E[a_1,,,,a_m]=K$ because $K$ contains $E$ as a subset and all the $a_i$'s.

We conclude that $K$ is a splitting field of $f$ over $E$

Is this proof correct or am i missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks fine to me

Comment: That looks good apart from one small detail: you need to say that the $a_i$ give $m$ distinct roots when counted according to their multiplicity. The way you have stated it the list $a_1, \ldots, a_m$ might miss out some root.

Comment: you are right ! thank you